# Error with PyXspec: Cannot read response file

Tags: python, xspec

I'm trying to load my first spectrum file with Xspec command within python, aka PyXspec.
But PyXspec tell me that it cannot read the response file 'file.rmf'.
My basic code is the follow:

```
from xspec import *

sp1=Spectrum('File_grp.pi')

AllData.show()
```

It is wired because, if i load the same file in the standard interactive Xspec mode, it works wihtout errors. Something like this:

```
unix> Xspec
xspec12> data 1:1 file_grp.pi
```

Comment: Are you sure about the path of your response file?
If it doesn't work, try as @Char suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting and replacing your response file, like
sp1.response = None
and then
sp1.response.frm = "file.rmf"